# ActiveRecords select(:id).collect vs. pluck(:id) methods: Why is pure AR "pluck" slower?

Tags: ruby, benchmarking

I am trying to get all the ids from my Article model. I can do it two ways:

```
 Article.select(:id).collect{|a| a.id}
  Article Load (2.6ms)  SELECT "articles"."id" FROM "articles"
```

OR

```
2.2.1 :006 > Article.pluck(:id)
   (4.3ms)  SELECT "articles"."id" FROM "articles"
```

What gives? Why is the AR slower than the Ruby version?

Even when I benchmark the Ruby method, it seems faster:

```
Benchmark.measure{Article.select(:id).collect{|a| a.id}}
  Article Load (1.9ms)  SELECT "articles"."id" FROM "articles"
 => #<Benchmark::Tms:0x007feb12060658 @label="", @real=0.026455502957105637, @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @stime=0.0, @utime=0.020000000000000018, @total=0.020000000000000018>
```

Comment: Did you disable caching in your database and in the Rails stack while testing? How many records do you have in your database? Are there any big columns (e.g. descriptions blogs) on the article table?

Comment: Check your benchmarks again: http://rubyinrails.com/2014/06/05/rails-pluck-vs-select-map-collect/

Comment: You ca  actually do it three way: "Article.all.collect{|a| a.id}" would be the default Ruby way, and if you benchmark that then you'll find it's very slow in comparison. Your first example is a mid-way approach between a fully-Rubyish method and one that is optimised for speed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your benchmark is inaccurate. First of all, as you can see, both executions on the database side triggers the same query

```
SELECT "articles"."id" FROM "articles"
```

Therefore, the database time should be considered irrelevant. Clearly the two queries had different execution time as shown by the console, but this is normal as if you run the same query 100 times the execution time can be different each time as it depends by a variety of variables such as the machine load, the database state, etc.

Since the database execution time can be considered equivalent, it's irrelevant for the benchmark.

Therefore, what you need to compare is the Ruby execution time and allocation. Pluck is supposed to be faster and more lightweight as compared to `collect` it doesn't allocate ActiveRecord objects, rather it returns only the selected values.

If you really want to benchmark the methods, you should mock the database time (which is clearly variable but irrelevant for this benchmark) and only benchmark allocation and the two different Ruby methods.

Long story short, `pluck` is generally more efficient.

Comment: Only problem with that argument is that pluck happens in the db, so removing it from the equation when doing the comparison is moot. Perhaps a better test would be to get an average as you eluded to in your point about running the query 100 times. Spot on in all other regards!

Comment: @Simore Could you provide a test prooving `pluck` is more efficient, please? I'm really curious, as in my own experiments it either fell into the margin of error, or was actually slower than `find_by!`. I used benchmark-ips, disabled query cache, SQL was identical. Quite surprising

Answer (score 5):

`select` is used to fetch records with specific attributes. It returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object.

`pluck` can be used the same way `select` is used, however it returns an array of selected attributes.

You can go through [this article](http://findnerd.com/list/view/Select-Vs-Pluck-in-Rails/19258/).

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't pay attention to the times recorded in the console and do a proper `benchmark` instead. Here's how much faster `select` can be when used in a nested query (about 30 times faster!)

```rb
[25] pry(main)> ActiveRecord::Base.logger = nil
[25] pry(main)> Benchmark.bmbm do |bm|
[25] pry(main)*   bm.report('select') do
[25] pry(main)*     2000.times do
[25] pry(main)*       ActiveRecord::Base.uncached do
[25] pry(main)*         Agenda.where(organization_id: Organization.limit(2).select(:id))
[25] pry(main)*       end
[25] pry(main)*     end
[25] pry(main)*   end
[25] pry(main)*   bm.report('pluck') do
[25] pry(main)*     2000.times do
[25] pry(main)*       ActiveRecord::Base.uncached do
[25] pry(main)*         Agenda.where(organization_id: Organization.limit(2).pluck(:id))
[25] pry(main)*       end
[25] pry(main)*     end
[25] pry(main)*   end
[25] pry(main)* end
Rehearsal ------------------------------------------
select   0.147064   0.001408   0.148472 (  0.149976)
pluck    1.494075   0.077501   1.571576 (  4.175919)
--------------------------------- total: 1.720048sec

             user     system      total        real
select   0.140494   0.000301   0.140795 (  0.140956)
pluck    1.200006   0.070174   1.270180 (  3.958814)
```

As has been explained, this is because in the first case the query is merged into the main query as a nested select, while with `pluck` a first query is executed to get the ids, which are then used to run the main query.

Bear in mind that this kinds of benchmarks always depend on your database, indexes, amount of rows you're dealing with, etc. When in doubt always run a quick benchmark to confirm this kind hypothesis!

For the record, here's a similar benchmark for your kind of "simple" query, which indeed shows `pluck` is faster, albeit not by a huge margin:

```rb
[27] pry(main)> Benchmark.bmbm do |bm|
[27] pry(main)*   bm.report('select') do
[27] pry(main)*     2000.times do
[27] pry(main)*       ActiveRecord::Base.uncached do
[27] pry(main)*         Organization.select(:id).collect(&:id)
[27] pry(main)*       end
[27] pry(main)*     end
[27] pry(main)*   end
[27] pry(main)*   bm.report('pluck') do
[27] pry(main)*     2000.times do
[27] pry(main)*       ActiveRecord::Base.uncached do
[27] pry(main)*         Organization.pluck(:id)
[27] pry(main)*       end
[27] pry(main)*     end
[27] pry(main)*   end
[27] pry(main)* end
Rehearsal ------------------------------------------
select   1.669422   0.080951   1.750373 (  4.318759)
pluck    1.081312   0.064770   1.146082 (  3.797270)
--------------------------------- total: 2.896455sec

             user     system      total        real
select   1.601772   0.069176   1.670948 (  4.298829)
pluck    1.094950   0.064165   1.159115 (  3.811094)
```