# Rails pluck vs select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was wondering what's the difference between `pluck` and `select`.

Base on the following code, the first one is faster than the second one. But I don't know what it causes.

```
c_ids = [123, 456]

# Good
m_ids = GcMission.joins(:mission).where(character: c_ids).select(:mission_id)
QuestionMission.where(mission_id: m_ids).pluck(:question_id)

# Bad
m_ids = GcMission.joins(:mission).where(character: c_ids).pluck(:mission_id)
QuestionMission.where(mission_id: m_ids).pluck(:question_id)
```

### Update

The question is different.

After several surveys,

```
m_ids = GcMission.joins(:mission).where(character: c_ids).select(:mission_id)

QuestionSetMission.where(mission_id: mission_ids).pluck(:question_set_id)
```

The above code will do the lazy query, it will only query once.

But the bad one will do twice.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32352278/activerecords-selectid-collect-vs-pluckid-methods-why-is-pure-ar-pluck) post.

Comment: Also [this one](http://gavinmiller.io/2013/getting-to-know-pluck-and-select/). It provides good examples with benchmarks.